# The Curl of $B$ when $J$ extends to infinity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, magnetostatics

Griffiths' proves Ampere's law:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf B = \mu_0 \mathbf J$$

For the case where $\mathbf J$ (the current density) can be confined within a finite volume.

Then Griffiths writes : "If $\mathbf J$ itself extends to infinity (as in the case of an infinite straight wire), the surface integral is still typically zero, though the analysis calls for greater care"

**Why is Ampere's law still holds (Or alternatively why the surface integral is zero) when $\mathbf J$ extends to infinity ?**

Comment: What surface integral?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the infinite wire penetrates a closed surface (homeomorphic to a sphere) at two points, one entering and the other leaving, if it intersects with the surface at all. As $\nabla \cdot J=0$, even though $J$ is great at the center of the thin wire, the surface integral on a volume is still $\int_{\partial V} J\cdot n=\int_V \nabla \cdot J=0.$ It is also evident from $\nabla\cdot \nabla \times=0$.